# ASP.Net Application SSO with ADFS

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

My Application in ASP.Net 4.0 Webform version. Application runs on SAAS based model. Deployed on Internet.

One of the client wants to use ADFS for SSO implementation.

When user logged in domain local intranet and try open Application deploy on Internet then he should be automatically logged into the application.

Process Flow will be

1. User Logged into Domain
2. Open Browser and try to open Internet application
3. Authenticate user with ADFS and Valid user then return the Claims

Any Blog or MSDN - how to configure ADFS (we did at our end but when user redirected to ADFS it again ask for Login from ADFS).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about IWA - refer [this](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/category/active-directory-federation-services-adfs/windows-integrated-authn/) (page down).

Note this is browser functionality.

Create RP trust [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-relying-party-trust).